# MySQL join want to exclude rows if not in second table

Tags: mysql, left-join, right-join

I am really breaking my head and hope for some help ;-)

I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    sum(ot.value) AS total_value,
    avg(ot.value) AS avg,
    count(ot.value) AS count
FROM
    orders_total ot,
    orders o
WHERE
    ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
AND ot.class = 'ot_total'
AND o.customers_name != 'Test Test'
AND o.date_purchased >= '2014-02-01T00:00:00'
AND o.date_purchased < '2014-03-01T00:00:00'
```

But I only want the values to be selected IF the orders_id is both in orders and orders_total tables.

So if the orders_id is missing in the orders_total table, I don't want it to be included in the query..

I tried left and right joins, like below, without any luck ;-(

```
SELECT
    sum(ot.value) AS total_value,
    avg(ot.value) AS avg,
    count(ot.value) AS count
FROM
    orders o
RIGHT JOIN orders_total ot ON (ot.orders_id = o.orders_id)
WHERE
    ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
AND ot.class = 'ot_total'
AND o.customers_name != 'Test Test'
AND o.date_purchased >= '2014-02-01T00:00:00'
AND o.date_purchased < '2014-03-01T00:00:00'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Bas

Comment: Please give example here [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Your original query should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this..Inner JOIN does the same thing that you want.

```
 SELECT
        sum(ot.value) AS total_value,
        avg(ot.value) AS avg,
        count(ot.value) AS count
    FROM
        orders o
    INNER JOIN orders_total ot ON (ot.orders_id = o.orders_id)
    WHERE
    AND ot.class = 'ot_total'
    AND o.customers_name != 'Test Test'
    AND o.date_purchased >= '2014-02-01T00:00:00'
    AND o.date_purchased < '2014-03-01T00:00:00'
```

Comment: OP is doing exactly the same thing. Only difference is: he is using implicit join syntax and you made it explicit.

Comment: Hi Charvee,
Thanks for the suggestion, highly appreciate your help!
Please see my comment to Gordon..
Both Gordon's as your query return exact same results as mine :-(
Thanks! Bas

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't think this is a `join` issue.  I think you are getting the wrong results out and *think* it is a join issue.  Your data is likely multiplying the results.  Perhaps you really want:

```
SELECT sum(ot.value) AS total_value,
       avg(ot.value) AS avg,
       count(ot.value) AS count
FROM orders_total ot
WHERE ot.class = 'ot_total' AND
      EXISTS (select 1
              from orders o
              where ot.orders_id = o.orders_id and 
                    o.customers_name <> 'Test Test' and
                    o.date_purchased >= '2014-02-01T00:00:00' and
                    o.date_purchased < '2014-03-01T00:00:00'
            );
```

I say this because your `select` is only using columns from the `orders_total` table.  This runs the risk that values will get multiplied due to the join.

Comment: Hi Gordon,

Thanks a lot for your feedback.
Strange thing is that still, my and your query are returning the exact same results. 

While I am 100% sure that in the orders_total table, a lot of orders are not present that are in the orders table.

Any suggestions?
Thanks again!
Bas